# Serialize Json string to object caseinsensitive

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to read Json string which should not be case sensitive

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
for (int i = 0; i < ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)result).Count; i++)
{
   Group.id = (string)result[i]["id"];
   Group.name = (string)result[i]["GroupName"];
   ...
   ...
```

I want the tags to be case insensitive. How do I achieve that? I have tried

```
    Group.id = (string)((JObject )result[i].GetValue("ID",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

But I get an error 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue'.

Json is:

```
{[
   {
     "id": "1",
     "State": "ON",
     "Override": "ON",
     "Lightoutput": 80,
     "GroupName": "new name for group 1"
   },
   {
     "id": "2",
     "State": "ON",
     "Override": "OFF",
     "Lightoutput": 100,
     "GroupName": "group 2"
   }
]}
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` google it.. there are plenty of examples

Comment: Can you show sample JSON? Why are you using `dynamic` here?

Comment: I have put the sample json in question. I can do without dynamic if I have a way

Comment: well, `JObject` does contain a definition for `GetValue` http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html

Comment: What you've posted is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `Group` class. Assuming it looks something like this:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Override { get; set; }

    public int LightOutput { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

you could just deserialize your array directly into a `List<Group>`:

```
var groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Group>>(json);
```

However, if you really want to use `JObject` and `JArray` for some reason, you should just use `JArray.Parse` and avoid `dynamic`:

```
JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);

for(int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
{
    var obj = arr[i].ToObject<JObject>();

    int id = (int)obj.GetValue(
        "ID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: This gives me a problem. I get 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not contain a definition for 'ToObject' and no extension method 'ToObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I cannot use your first approach because there is a key word used in Json 'override'. In my groups class I have used 'over_ride'. In your first approach over_ride is always null as it does not match the json

Comment: The first approach works well - but I my case I have to handle 'override' seperately

Comment: @user2837961: What version of JSON.NET are you using?

Comment: The version of Nwetonsoft.Json is 3.5.0.0

Comment: You can also use `[JsonProperty("override")]` to populate the value correctly, FYI

Comment: Yes that is what I have used but I can't use 'override' property in a class and also if I have to use case insensitive Json property, I have to check for Override,override and OVERRIDE for most common cases

Comment: @user2837961: Ah, that makes sense. The version of Newtonsoft.Json you're using is very old... Any chance you could upgrade? That's why the second example is not working for you I bet.

Comment: I upgraded to version 6. The second example works as well. Thank you